# How to have a Google Cloud Monitoring graph with a small legend?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-cloud-monitoring

I would like to have a Cloud Monitoring graph with a legend at the bottom like this:
[image]
The graph above is taken from the official documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/working-with-legends

What I have is think kind of graph without any default legend. Of course, I can click on expand but it is not the same:
[image]

How can I have the same thing as the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in the dashboard toolbar, click settings, Settings and then select Condensed or Table. To show or hide the legend of a particular chart, click Expand legend, or select Expand chart legend in the more_vert More chart options menu.

Comment: this is what I see when I click on the settings wheel: https://imgur.com/a/AGmhHfy